# C# DBF file error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

Tags: c#, dbf, oledbdataadapter

I am working on a C# program that will read DBF files and import the tables into a MySQL database. I am able to get the directory of all the DBF files' location and read most of the DBF files. The problem is 2 out of the 17 DBF files will throws an exception with myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

Here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\\", @"\\"));
    string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=dBase III";
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

    try
    {
        myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4));
        string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4);
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

        myAccessConn.Open();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

        myAccessConn.Close();

    }
    MessageBox.Show("End");
}
```

These are the Error Message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'SomeFile'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

What is causing this? I've printed out dir, file.name, and strAccessSelect, and everything looks spelled correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank You!

--UPDATE--

I have checked the files permissions and every user has full privileges.

Not sure how much this will help, but sometimes when I rename the file (ex: SomeFile1) it will work and I will not get an error message... Most of the time this will not work.

Comment: It would be useful to see how do you build the `strAccessSelect` string

Comment: @Steve Wow, how could I forget maybe the most important part... Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be sure that the filename is correct

```
string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
```

And if this doesn't work the only possible cause is a file locked by some other process or a permission problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was strAccessConn. I had to use the following code:

```
if ((file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4) == "SomeFile1") || (file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4) == "SomeFile2"))
{
    strAccessConn = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" + dir + ";Collating Sequence=machine;";
}
else
{
    strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=dBase IV";
}
```

Each file required a different connection string